# Word or term comprising payor and payee

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word or term that encapsulates both the payor and payee. ideally it would be used in a bookkeeping context.

Example:

> Company X both receives and and sends payments to company Y. In the bookkeeping transactions they are ....

Please, do not feel limited to the example given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though I agree that *parties* is the generally used hypernym, another term you can use is ***transactors***.

ODO:

> **[transactor](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/transactor)** *NOUN*
>
> Example sentences:
>   ‘Better information improves markets by
>   permitting transactors to make more informed choices.’
>   ‘Only an
>   eighth of the transactors are in the public service: their numbers
>   have been growing slightly more slowly than those in the private
>   sector.’
>
> **[transact](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/transact)**
>   *VERB*
>   [WITH OBJECT] **Conduct or carry out (business)**
>   ‘traders transact business in the public exchange’
>   [no object] ‘the dealer
>   must know the price at which he is prepared to transact’

Answer (score 2):

> a word or term that encapsulates both the payor and payee.

I believe that would be ***party*** or ***party to transaction***.

> ***party*** a person or people forming one side in an agreement or dispute : *a contract between two parties.*

The New Oxford American Dictionary

> **party to the transaction** - a party of people taking a role in legal proceedings

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/party+to+the+transaction)

> **payee** - Party to whom a bill of exchange (such as a check or draft) is made payable.

[Business Dictionary](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/payee.html)

> A third-party transaction is a business deal involving a buyer, a
>   seller and a third party.

[Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/third-party-transaction.asp#ixzz4MkhmiNDD)

> The party issuing a check is called the payor (in legal parlance) or
>   the payer (in common communication). The party whose name appears on
>   the check or to whom the check is issued is called the payee.

[Bookkeeping](https://books.google.com/books?id=lGFUJ7GagcoC&pg=PA114&dq=bookkeeping%20payor%20payee%20party&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimtJi9hdLPAhVDSRoKHWEZBBoQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=bookkeeping%20payor%20payee%20party&f=false)

Comment: For a transaction or a contract, one may refer to "concerned parties " or "involved parties".

Answer (score 0):

> participant

It is used a lot for referring to two or more entities doing financial transactions in this glossary: [A glossary of terms used in payments and settlement systems](http://www.bis.org/cpmi/glossary_030301.pdf)

excerpt:

> a mechanism in some settlement systems to assist a participant to
>   borrow money from or lend money to another participant against
>   collateral held in the system.

Comment: edited answer to provide link to the example.
I must say I like the answer of @michael-hor257k better

Comment: Your source defines *participant* as "a party who participates in a transfer system."  They further define *transfer system* as "a generic term covering interbank funds transfer systems and exchange-for-value systems." That would make *participant* someone who has signed up as a user of a system (e.g. SWIFT) - not a party to an individual transaction.